# node modules of modules install in unwanted spot

Tags: node.js, module, installation

Hello and thanks for reading,

Historically, when I ran the command:

```
npm install module
```

Module would install in the node_modules dir of the current working directory. This still happens, however, the modules that the module use, is now installing alongside the original module, so that my node_modules dir might look like:

```
./node_modules/module/
./node_modules/module-of-that-module/
```

When it used to look like:

```
./node_modules/module/node_modules/module-of-that-module/
```

I suppose it might boil down to preference, but I don't really like the sub-modules installing alongside the main module I was trying to install, as my main node_modules directory became cluttered with hundreds of random modules fast. Also it seems kind of strange for the structure to be this way if the modules of modules need different versions.

Can anyone please explain what changed here? And how I might change it back? I tried to find a solution prior to writing this, but it's unclear to me how to search around this issue or what category it falls under.

Comment: you upgraded to npm 3.x https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0 That feature doesn't appear to have an off switch, so, either get used to it, or downgrade.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I suppose this may be a change that would be best embraced from the sound of that release log.